# How to use all available computing powers in a function

Tags: python, fast-ai

I need a function that changes their size for a given number of photos, use all available computing powers. I found that I can use function `parallel` for this, but I don't know how to use it properly.

Here is my code:

```py
from random import randint
from fastai.core import parallel

import cv2

def image_conversion(list, size, directory, conversion):
    if conversion == '--resize':
        for img in list:
            imageAsNumpy = cv2.imread(img)
            dim = (size[1], size[0])
            resized = cv2.resize(imageAsNumpy, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            writeStatus = cv2.imwrite(directory + img, resized)
            if writeStatus is True:
                print('Imagine written successfully!')
            else:
                print('Something went wrong!')
    elif conversion == '--random crop':
        for img in list:
            image = cv2.imread(img)
            height, width = image.shape[:2]
            h = randint(0, height)
            w = randint(0, width)
            cropped = image[h:h+width, w:w+height]
            status = cv2.imwrite(directory + img, cropped)
            if status is True:
                print('Imagine cropped')
            else:
                print('Problem')
```

But when I tried to call `parallel` function it fails every time, for example the progress bar goes to a 100%, but with none of the work is completed. Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "computing powers"? I'm not familiar with that term - or, at least, I can think of a couple different things you might mean but I'm not sure which.

Comment: @DavidZ By this I mean using all available processes (CPU, GPU).